# how to use gtk2.0 2.24.6-0ubuntu5 on Ubuntu 12.04 running gtk2.0 2.24.10-0ubuntu6?

Tags: 12.04, gtk

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 which is using "gtk2.0 2.24.10-0ubuntu6".
The GTK applications that I am using run on the older version "gtk2.0 2.24.6-0ubuntu5".
How do I revert or use the older version of GTK?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you give an example of a simple application that uses this older version?

Answer (score 0):

You need to recompile your old app for the new lib.